# Featherlight Gallery - Youtube Video

Tags: featherlight.js

I implemented a featherlight gallery, but I want 1 of the gallery images to open as a youtube video.

I implemented it like below... but the video opens in a real small window (only if you are clicking through the slides of the gallery).

In the example below, the 3rd picture, when clicked individually will show the video in an iframe... that part works great.  However, if you are viewing the pictures in the "gallery mode" and start with picture 1, click the arrow to picture 2, click the arrow to picture 3... the video will open, but not in an iframe... it will be in a small video window.

```
<div data-featherlight-gallery data-featherlight-filter="a">

  <a href="http://www.somesite.com/picture1.jpg"><img src="http://www.somesite.com/picture1.jpg" /></a>
 
  <a href="http://www.somesite.com/picture2.jpg"><img src="http://www.somesite.com/picture2.jpg" /></a>
 
  <a href="https://youtu.be/h4T_LlK1VE4" data-featherlight="iframe" data-featherlight-iframe-width="960" data-featherlight-iframe-height="540"><img src="http://www.somesite.com/picture3.jpg" /></a>

</div>
```

In a nutshell, how do I use the gallery feature... and still have a youtube video open properly in an iframe.